# How can I toggle a task on and off with a single powershell script?

Tags: powershell

Be gentle, I can barely write a batch file and this is me throwing my head against a wall trying to get it to stick.

I've tried this:

```
$TaskName = "ReconcileFeatures"

Get-ScheduledTask $TaskName | Enable-ScheduledTask
Get-ScheduledTask $TaskName | Disable-ScheduledTask
```

Which obviously doesn't work.  Well it does sort of.   It will disable the task, but does not function as a toggle.

Then I tried this which is probably heading in the proper direction, but not knowing much of any type of code I'm sure has some large fundamental flaws.

```
$TaskName = "ReconcileFeatures"

if (Get-ScheduledTask $TaskName).State -eq 'Disabled')
{
    Do Enable-ScheduledTask
}

elseif (Get-ScheduledTask $TaskName).State -eq 'Ready')
{
    Do Disable-ScheduledTask
}
```

Through past reading it seems people around here tend to harbor disdain towards writing code for others, however I learn a lot better from example and it will not only help me out directly, but give me something to reference.

EDIT: For future browsers, version 1 and 3 suggested below by steven accomplish what I set out to do.  Version 2 which was using my version resulted in an error due to missing the path to the task.  A working version is

```
$TaskName = "ReconcileFeatures"
$TaskPath = "\Microsoft\Windows\Flighting\FeatureConfig\"

if ( (Get-ScheduledTask $TaskName).State -eq 'Disabled' )
{
    Enable-ScheduledTask $TaskPath -TaskName $TaskName
}
elseif ( (Get-ScheduledTask $TaskName).State -eq 'Ready' )
{
    Disable-ScheduledTask $TaskPath -TaskName $Taskname
}
```

Comment: That code looks good, other than needing a second opening parenthesis after the `if` and `elseif`.

Comment: So like this will work?  
if ((Get-ScheduledTask $TaskName).State -eq 'Disabled') if thats what you mean?  total layman here lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice and clean way to do this may be:

```
$Taskname = "ReconcileFeatures"
$Task = Get-ScheduledTask $Taskname

Switch ($Task.State)
{
    'Ready'    { Disable-ScheduledTask -InputObject $Task; Break }
    'Disabled' { Enable-ScheduledTask -InputObject $task; Break  }
}
```

This is the equivalent of an IF/ElseIf statement but I think for this purpose `Switch` is a little cleaner.

You don't need a `Do` which is a keyword to indicate a loop, or for that matter any other call type command.  In fact, as noted by other comments, if you weren't missing some parens your code was pretty close.  Something like below may also work:

```
$TaskName = "ReconcileFeatures"

if ( (Get-ScheduledTask $TaskName).State -eq 'Disabled' )
{
    Enable-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName
}
elseif ( (Get-ScheduledTask $TaskName).State -eq 'Ready' )
{
    Disable-ScheduledTask -TaskName $Taskname
}
```

Another cool approach is to store the code in a hash table keyed on the states you are looking for. This is a little more advanced, but I was playing around with it so figured why not include it.

```
$TaskName = "ReconcileFeatures"
$Task = Get-ScheduledTask $Taskname

$TaskStates = @{
    Disabled = { Enable-ScheduledTask -InputObject $Task  }
    Ready    = { Disable-ScheduledTask -InputObject $Task }
}

& $TaskStates[[String]$Task.State]
```

This will user the call operator `&` to invoke the script block stored in the hash table by looking them up using the current state of the task.  The only complication, `.State` is an enum type so it won't look up the hash key unless you convert it to a string.

Incidentally the possible state values are:

1. Unknown
2. Disabled
3. Queued
4. Ready
5. Running

Comment: thank you for this.  exactly what  I was looking for.  3rd way definitely over my head at the moment but the first two will be perfect for my use and perfect to use to build off of in the future.  I appreciate you taking the time to share and explain!

Comment: running the version akin to the OP results in an error.  Seems to require a TaskPath.  Will update the OP in case anyone comes across in the future.